# Translating "aquaponics"

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

In English, [aquaponics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquaponics) describes a system combining aquaculture with hydroponics in a symbiotic relationship. I haven't been able to find this word in any Spanish-English dictionary, and the Wikipedia page doesn't have a Spanish translation.

Is there an accepted word for aquaponics in Spanish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [Hydroponics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroponics) there's the term [Hidroponía](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidropon%C3%ADa) which is also accepted in [RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=hidropon%C3%ADa).

Googling around I find that people uses the term Acuaponía. In [google](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=%22Acuapon%C3%ADa%22) there are 12,500 results, but "**Acuaponía**"is not an accepted term by RAE. It's difficult for RAE to add a new word for every technical term.

Answer (score 1):

A [report](http://ag.arizona.edu/azaqua/ista/Colombia/TILAPIAROJA2006.pdf) from Colombia hosted by the University of Arizona uses the word *acuapónicos*. *Acuaponía* appears to be an acceptable alternative according to [Google](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&cp=5&gs_id=j&xhr=t&q=acuaponia&tok=fxORkO1lWyvbZBWH03cZLQ&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&site=&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=acuap&aq=0&aqi=g1g-s3&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=a832e4bee034e5be&biw=1920&bih=995).

Answer (score 1):

In this scientific [paper published in Spanish Journal of Agricultural Research](http://revistas.inia.es/index.php/sjar/article/view/1758/1447) they use two forms:

> Resumen
>
> **Aquaponica**: integrando la tasa de alimentación de peces y la producción de iones residuales  para la hidroponía de fresas
>
> **La aquaponía** es la ciencia de integrar la acuicultura intensiva con la producción de plantas en sistemas con agua en recirculación. (...)

Comment: The English prefix Aqua is usually translated with the Spanish prefix "Acua" (with C, which means water). I don't know any accepted word by RAE starting with "aqua" but there are several starting with "acua" (acuático, acuario,...). So if RAE aggregates any word for "Aquaponics" it will likely start with "Acua", in my honest opinion.